# Angular2 .gitignore

Tags: javascript, git, angular, gitignore

I'm setting up an Angular 2 sample project. Is my `.gitignore` enough already or did I miss anything?

```
node_modules
typings
jspm_packages
bower_components
app/**/*.js
app/**/*.map
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`angular-cli` generates

```
# See http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# compiled output
/dist
/tmp
/out-tsc

# dependencies
/node_modules

# IDEs and editors
/.idea
.project
.classpath
.c9/
*.launch
.settings/
*.sublime-workspace

# IDE - VSCode
.vscode/*
!.vscode/settings.json
!.vscode/tasks.json
!.vscode/launch.json
!.vscode/extensions.json

# misc
/.sass-cache
/connect.lock
/coverage
/libpeerconnection.log
npm-debug.log
testem.log
/typings

# e2e
/e2e/*.js
/e2e/*.map

# System Files
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
```

Comment: a `ng new MyProject` doesnt include any `.gitignore` file ...?

Comment: I don't know why. I'm sure it should. This is the file it should generate https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/e9372d3c11af622f026d391088e173eb5c66bda9/packages/%40angular/cli/blueprints/ng/files/gitignore

Comment: thanks! found the issue. ng cli did not update properly due to http://stackoverflow.com/a/43525586/3779853 .

Comment: What about /e2e/*.ts?

Comment: Now at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/6fc6e84/packages/schematics/angular/workspace/files/__dot__gitignore.template

Comment: Year 2021 - This file is automatically generated when the app is created - ng version 11 - npm version 12 - @phil294

Answer (score 2):

Updated auto-generated `.gitignore` for Angular `15.0.0` by `"@angular/cli": "~15.0.2"` includes `/.angular/cache` and other new folders that should be ignored in Angular:

```
# See http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# Compiled output
/dist
/tmp
/out-tsc
/bazel-out

# Node
/node_modules
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log

# IDEs and editors
.idea/
.project
.classpath
.c9/
*.launch
.settings/
*.sublime-workspace

# Visual Studio Code
.vscode/*
!.vscode/settings.json
!.vscode/tasks.json
!.vscode/launch.json
!.vscode/extensions.json
.history/*

# Miscellaneous
/.angular/cache
.sass-cache/
/connect.lock
/coverage
/libpeerconnection.log
testem.log
/typings

# System files
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
```