# I uninstalled angular-cli using npm uninstall -g angular-cli. However, it is still installed when I check ng --version

Tags: angularjs, angular, npm, angular-cli

What is going on here?

On my laptop, I ran `npm uninstall -g angular-cli`, and it is gone.

However, on my desktop, I can still run `ng --version` after removing angular-cli globally.

What is going on and how can I fix this?

Comment: What do you get when you run `npm ls -g --depth=0`?

Comment: Maybe you can try to uninstall using npm uninstall -g angular-cli --save to remove the dependancy  added in the package.json

Answer (score 3):

There is always a global installation and a local one in your project.

So run `npm uninstall angular-cli` in your project path and its gone finally! :)

Answer (score 2):

maybe you need to clean cache, try this:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with updating angular-cli, `ng -v` was always returning the same version after few installs/uninstalls of `angular-cli` or new `@angular/cli`. The problem was that in nodejs installation folder there were `ng` and `ng.exe` files. I removed them, installed @angular/cli and had fresh version of it.

Comment: Any idea why these file were installed here? Do newer versions of the CLI have an easier upgrade process?

Comment: @wickdninja not sure right now why these files were in nodejs folder. Right now I am using new @angular/cli and really cannot complain, already upgraded it about 2-3 times.

Comment: Yeah once I got those files cleaned up I was able to update to the latest without any issue & uninstall cleanly. So I'm assuming an older version of the CLI used those files, and we probably won't have to worry about it going forward.

Answer (score 1):

Your npm version might have changed, relocating the binaries folder. Thus, npm cannot uninstall something which it does not know it existed in the first place. In unix, `ls -l $(whereis ng)` might help you out eliminate old folders.