# Why does git ignore node_modules folder by default?

Tags: angular, git, github, node-modules, gitignore

I created an angular project and pushed it in my `github` repository.

When I looked at the pushed files, the `node_modules` folder was missing, I didn't declare anywhere to ignore this folder, is this a default behavior? If yes then why?

Also, when I decided to delete all my repositories on github and create only one instead where I will check-in all my projects, once initializing `git init` and pushing changes, git started pushing `node_modules` folder for all projects and it took a lot of time.

What makes `git` ignore or not ignore the `node_modules` folder all by itself? I haven't set this configuration anywhere by myself.

Thank you.

Comment: The angular cli adds a gitignore file with node_modules listed in it. No magic here.

Comment: @Royson Does it add the gitignore file even when I have initialized git in folder yet? Why didn't it add the gitignore file when I initialized a simple directory? because I wasn't inside an angular project?

Comment: Depending on the size of your Angular project, `node_modules` will take up disk space, thus, Angular includes `node_modules` on your .gitignore.

Comment: @Jaguar-515 at what stage does angular create the .gitignore file? when a project is created?

Comment: @MuhammadFaraz I believe it's created during `ng new`?

Comment: Yes i just tested it, I didn't do git init yet there is a .git folder and .gitignore file. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git` does not ignore `node_modules` by default. It ignores nothing by default. The angular cli adds `node_modules` to `.gitignore`, which caused `git` to ignore it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37187110/5666087 for more info, and see angular cli's github repo for the [specific .gitignore file added](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/fc1fda266354ca3291b8045be6cee21f62204902/packages/schematics/angular/workspace/files/__dot__gitignore.template). You will see that `/node_modules` is listed there.

You should not version control `node_modules`, because those are artifacts you can get easily with `npm install` or `yarn install`.

Creating a git repository outside of a angular project (e.g., in a new directory) does not add a `.gitignore` file, so `node_modules` is not ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Angular CLI generates a file in the root of the project where you open the angular project named **.gitignore**.

This is one of the default workspace configuration files, **angular cli generates** automatically when you create your project with **ng new** cli command. The purpose of this file is to **store intentionally untracked files, that GIT should ignore**.

You can place the paths of all such folders / files that you want to ignore in git in this file. Its content by default look like this..

```
projectname/dist/
projectname/node_modules/
```

The **dist** and **node_modules** folders are placed in it by default. You can add any folder / file name that you want to put in ignore list in this file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you generate the `angular` project using `angular-cli`?

If yes, then in generating the project it automatically generated a `.gitignore` file to ignore `node_modules`.

`git` will only ignore a folder, or a file only when it is set in the `.gitignore` file.
And in your case, it has already been done automatically in the `.gitigore` file `angular-cli` generated for you.